# Magento website not accessible in browser via VPN (Apache logs shows http 302 status)

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, redirect, apache

I have deployed the magento website using bitnami magento stack on Azure platform. Also for security I have included this in VPN and connect to the server(SSH) via VPN client.

Even after all magento services are running properly on the server I cannot access the magento website via internet and its redirecting the server public IP to the VPN server IP.
**Summary:**
[enter link description here](https://bitnami.com/stack/magento)
I used the above link to create server on Azure using the predefined template provided. It already has Magento, apache, Mariadb, varnish, PHP, etc preinstalled. We just have to run the master script and start all the services and can access it via browser. Also please note that the server is inside a VPN network so inorder to connect to server or its deployed webapps I have to connect to VPN using VPN client.

```
Now the issue is its whenever I tried to access the magento website via server's public ip its showing http status 302 in the apache access log.
```

[image]

```
Also I tried the following:
    a. running a separate node server on the same magento server on 80 port and it was accessible via browser.
    b. Deployed a similar bitnami stack magento server just without the VPN and it was accessible via internet.
```

Do we have to do any extra configurations in Apache/other services when using a VPN ?

Kindly help me out in this.

Comment: When you say "deployed" did you post an image or you went through the installation of magento and now its just not accessible?  I suggest you create a php file with "hello world" text in the root of the installation and see if you can access it directly. If you cannot then its a web server issue - if you can please provide more details.

Comment: https://bitnami.com/stack/magento  I used the following link to create server on Azure using the template provided. It already has magento, apache, mariadb, varnish, php,etx preinstalled. We just have to run the master script and start all the services.

Comment: @SR_Magento  Also please note that the server is inside a VPN network so inorder to connect to server or its deployed webapps I have to connect to VPN using VPN client.
 
 Now the issue is its whenever I tried to access the magento website via server's public ip its showing http status 302 in the apache access log

Comment: @SR_Magento  Also I tried the following:
a. running a separate node server on the same magento server on 80 port and it was accessible via browser.
b. Deployed a similar bitnami stack magento server just without the VPN and it was accessible via internet.
  
Do we have to do any extra configurations in Apache/other services when using a VPN?